# Is there any way to retain only the failed test's video in Selenoid?

Tags: selenoid

Is there any way to configure Selenoid-video file to detect and delete the passed test videos and retain only failed test videos? if not, rename or tag the failed test video as failed ?

Comment: Why not have a callback function, and if test passed, send API request to Selenoid and delete video

Answer (score 0):

Selenoid only automates browsers and is even not aware that you are running tests in these browsers. Because of that this is not possible and doing this is tests code responsibility.